# CGridView Filter doesn't work when you add more than one button to the CButtonColumn

Tags: php, yii, cbuttoncolumn

I have a CGridView as follows,

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'order-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
'filter'=>$model,
'columns'=>array(
    'order_id',
    //'ordered_datetime',
    'customer_id',
    'status',
    //'delivery_address',
    array(
        'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        'template' => '{view} {rollback} {receive}{pack} {dispatch}{delivered}',
        'htmlOptions'=>array('width'=>'250px'),
        'buttons'=>array(
            'receive'=>array(
                'id'=>'receive',
                'name'=>'receive',
                'url'=>'$this->grid->controller->createUrl("/shop/order/admin&received=true", array("id"=>$data->order_id,"asDialog"=>1,"gridId"=>$this->grid->id))',
                'type'=>'submit',
                'imageUrl'=>'/mdg/images/Receive1.png',
                'visible'=>'($data->status=="pending")?true:false;'
             ),
                             'rollback'=>array(
                'id'=>'rollback',
                'name'=>'rollback',
                                     'click'=>''
                'url'=>'$this->grid->controller->createUrl("/shop/order/admin&rollback=true", array("id"=>$data->order_id,"asDialog"=>1,"gridId"=>$this->grid->id))',
                'imageUrl'=>'/mdg/images/rollback.jpg',
                'visible'=>'($data->status=="pending")?false:true;'
             ),


        ),
    ),
),
)); ?>
```

And When I add one more button to the buttons array, the filter doesn't work. Any Idea why that is?

Comment: What are you adding, exactly?

Comment: another item to the buttons array... for example 'rollback'

Comment: 'receive'=>array(.........),
'pack'=>array(......),

likewise...

Comment: I understand that, but could you post the code? There are probably some javascript errors, since the filter is javascripty/ajaxy.

Comment: ok.. i edited my code..in this state the filter doesnt work... with one item it works...

Comment: Well, that `'click'=>'',` doesn't look good to me, otherwise check the javascript console when you initiate a filter.

Comment: ok.. i found the error.. silly really it's coz i have put an attribute as 'click'=>''..when i commented that off, it worked..
Thanks for ur help. I'll edit the code now.

Comment: oh!! ya... thanks alot!! that was the problem. :)

Comment: @Örs i think you should add that as answer and let era accept. let's keep the unanswered count down

Comment: @bool.dev ok. @era please edit this question again and leave the `'click'=>'',` part there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an extra `click => '',` in the `recieve` button's array.